# Wordpress - unable to edit page but am able to view it in view site

Tags: wordpress

[image]Wordpress - unable to edit page but am able to view it in view site.

When i click on edit page , it is showing the EDIT page but am unable to see anything in description.

However when i click on view site, it shows up the site.

Any help would be great.

View site is working fine as shown below :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi can you please post the error you're seeing?

Comment: No errors, but the edit is blank. Am not sure on where to edit.

Comment: Is this a template that you downloaded and integrated or did yu created this on your own ? ?

Comment: This is an existing project. I have managed to set it up in my local. And want to make some changes.

Comment: There will be a list of files under the name of the project i guess in your xamp -> htdocs ->"project_name" -> wp-content->Themes -> "theme _name". every pages will be like page-home,page-cart, etc .. Have you checked that ?

Comment: Yeah am inside one of the pages , and am unable to edit any page. But am able to view them using View Site.

Comment: Added a screen.

Comment: You are talking about the wordpress backend rite ! am asking you to check on your computer harddisk drive . check the path i mentioned in your computer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163383/discussion-between-jackson-and-ashwinsakthi).

Comment: Also look at the theme documentation, it will tell you how things can be edited that are customisable or outside the normal function, as this appears to be. Home might be run by Widgets, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. This can be a PHP template. If you have access to your FTP, try to find a file called `page-tindel-lawrence.php` in **wp-content > themes > yourTheme**.
2. I can't see in your screenshot if there's a 'Template' assigned, just under 'Parent' in 'Parent Attributes'. If so, there will be a PHP template with the code.
3. Try to change the text editor between 'Visual' and 'Text', sometimes the content can be bugged here.
4. Open 'Screen Options' tab and see if there's any option unselected related to the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This can be any template file, if you don't want to debug then one plugin will help you a lot, once you installed and activate it and navigate that page you will find easily all the information of that page like template name, rewrite rule etc..

Plugin link is - https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-this/